# SharePoint - Approaching Website Storage Limit Email

Tags: sharepoint, email, size, limit

How can i go about changing the distribution list as well as the email text for the email that goes out to site collection admin when a site collection approaches it's size limit?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email goes out to anybody who is listed as a site collection administrator for that site collection. So if you would like to change the dist list, you need to update that security group.

As for changing the text of the email, the email template is defined in the following folder: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\1033\FPEXT.MSG. I am not sure if there is a way to override this text without changing this OOB file though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no security group for site collection administrators, each site collection has exactly 2 such account (aka primary and secondary site collection administrator). Changing those will update the recipient list. Regards, Kees.

Comment: You are correct if you are modifying the site collection administrators through the central admin. But if you go to the settings page of a site collection, you can add more than 2 administrators.